# "I am slipped down by a skateboard." Is is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

> I am slipped down by a skateboard.

Or

> Skateboard slips me down.

Are both of these correct?
If these are wrong, how to make it correct?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Are you saying you slipped and fell, and you happened to land nearby a skateboard? Or that you rode a skateboard down a half-pipe? Or something else?

Comment: Umm, I mean I fall and land on the ground because the skateboard slips me.

Comment: Do you mean **I slipped *off* my skateboard**?

Comment: You could say "I fell off the skateboard" or "The skateboard slipped out from under me".

Comment: No, no, sorry, I didn't describe it well.

Comment: I mean went into a garage, it was messy, and it was dark. So I accidently stepped on a skateboard and fell off.

Comment: But I would like to combine this in to a short sentence.

Comment: Yeah, I can't tell what you mean either. I imagine it's either, "I slipped off my skateboard," which you'd use if you were on it and riding it when it slipped out from under you and you fell down, or, "I slipped on a skateboard," like if you were walking along, didn't notice the skateboard on the ground there, stepped on it by accident, and fell down because it slipped out from under you. But I'm not confident enough that either of those are what you need to put this as an answer. Maybe you actually mean "tripped," or any number of possibilities. It's hard to tell from your limited explantion.

Comment: If you accidentally stepped on the skateboard in the dark, the simplest way to put it would be **I tripped over a skateboard**.

Comment: *I accidentally stepped **on** a skateboard and fell off*, can be reduced to, *I slipped **on** a skateboard*.  If you were riding the skateboard and fell off, you would be more likely to say, *I fell **off** a skateboard [that I was riding].*

Comment: The exact specified context is slightly unusual. But the "correct" preposition here is *I slipped **on** a skateboard* - same as, for example, *He slipped **on a banana skin**.*

Comment: OK, thank you yall. I know my problem now. Thanks!!!